# classic asp - ms access update problem (The Microsoft Jet database engine stopped)

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

no problem for single user but I get the following errors when testing with multiple users at once.

**ERROR 1 :** 
The Microsoft Jet database engine stopped the process because you or another user tried to change the same data at the same time.

**OR**

**ERROR 2 :** Could not update; currently locked.

```
Set data = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
data.connectionstring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE="&Server.MapPath("db/db.mdb")
data.open 

set rs = server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
rs.open "select * from users where id="&user_id,data,1,3

rs("ip") = ip
rs.update

rs.close : set rs = NOthing : data.close : set data= NOthing
```

Comment: Well, Microsoft is rather explicit everywhere that you should _not_ use Access as a database for a website or service. There's bound to be locking conflicts and concurrency issues if you do.

Comment: The update should only take a split second, so it looks like the connection isn't closed even though you try to. Why, I cannot say.

Comment: Do you have your jet database open in the Access desktop program?  If you do that will certainly "lock" it for other users - ie your website.  A jet database is fine as the backend of a low traffic website if you close your recordset and connection once you've extracted the data you need, and you have done this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try:

```
dim bensql
bensql="select * from users where id="&user_id
rs.Open bensql, data,3,3
if not rs.eof then
    rs("ip") = ip
    rs.update
end if
rs.close
```

maybe because another user tried to change the same data at the same time, query can't determine rs.eof or not